# Error converting a binary CSV file to a TXT file

Tags: c++, binary, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

My problem is that i'm getting this error:

(terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
what():  stoi)

I have to input a binary CSV file run the syntax and save the output in a TXT file. Any help would be appreciated

```
string linea;
vector <string> numeros;


ifstream entrada("ECG_pueba_1.csv", ios::binary);
ofstream signal( "datos_de_senial.txt" );

int pos =0;

while(getline(entrada, linea)){
    istringstream in(linea);
    string num;
    if(pos==0){
        while (getline(in, num, ',')){
            numeros.push_back(num);
        }

    }

    regex re(",");
    string csv = linea;
    vector<string> data(sregex_token_iterator(csv.begin(),csv.end(),re,-1), {});

    // itero a traves de "data"
    for (vector<string>::iterator iter = data.begin(); iter != data.end(); ++iter) {

        // leo el valor
        int value = stoi(*iter);
        // paso al siguiente valor
        ++iter; 
        int repeatCount = stoi(*iter);

        // muestro por consola
        for (int i=0; i < repeatCount; ++i)
            signal << value << "\n";
    }

}

signal.close();
```

Edit: okay, first thanks for the replies, i'm very new to c++ and english, i'm still trying to understand basic concepts. So i will try to explain myself better.

I have a CVS file that have this kind of data inside (0ÒÐà0ê(ót-14ãK0áK†††œ2K`9v†€=K0ãKÌótœ2KZš<ót 7K>K€>KãK0áKøƒøƒøƒœ2K@9v)

As i know it is in binary, and i can read it with this lines:

```
ifstream leer_ECG8("ECG_pueba_1.csv", ios::binary);
        leer_ECG8.read((char*)(&leer_linea_final), sizeof(linea_final));

        for( unsigned int i =0;i<leer_linea_final.size();i++)
            cout<<leer_linea_final[i];

        leer_ECG1.close();
```

And i get: (ELC_: 1238145210288246184252720524-2298-490...)

The final objective is to take "ECG_pueba_1.csv" and convert it to numbers to operate.

I don't know if is understandable or everything is wrong, if so let me know and i delete the post. Thank you all!

Link to the file if is worth something: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GsyDy-QR84UeK6-Oa-AlYdrG9pUch6dp

Comment: Without a link to the "binary csv" or a hexdump of the first 512bytes or so, it's really not possible to know what you need. There really is no such thing as a "binary csv". In a binary file the storage is by type-size, delimiters like a comma are not necessary. There is also no concept of a "line" in a binary file.

Comment: There's no such thing as a *binary CSV file*. A CSV file is text format, with values separated by commas (thus the **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues extension). It's no more *binary* than any other plain text file - in fact, it is already a text file, so no *conversion* is necessary.

Comment: Your exception says that you try to stoi some string that is not int. So you should catch that exception somewhere not let it to crash your program or not to feed stoi wrong texts.

Comment: Just to your error message:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stoi 

It means you are giving std::stoi() bad input, so it is throwing a std::invalid_argument (shorturl.at/yHIN2) exception that you are not catching. std::stoi, std::stol, std::stoll (shorturl.at/diOU3) Exceptions: std::invalid_argument if no conversion could be performed so you need to double-check your input string values that you are trying to convert.

Comment: @Ken My logic would say the binary file contains csv data - else he would have to re engineer/crack it (http://www.iwriteiam.nl/Ha_HTCABFF.html) right Mauricio? And I guess that is what you want to tell him that he needs to edit the text Ken, right?

Comment: @Ivanovic: My logic tells me that the poster hasn't provided anything meaningful about the input file at all, yet is expecting us to debug issues with how it's being read. It's very difficult to help with problems that are not actually described. It's sort of like someone asking for help fixing their Porsche Carrera but posting a picture of a skateboard. They're not the same.

Comment: In a binary file, each item read is a *byte* or *octet*.  How does one tell the difference between the number 44 (0x2C) and whether it is a comma?  Also, what happens if 0x2C appears in a multibyte integer?